# Тире в предложении: "Мне всё равно, за кого она голосует — я собираюсь жениться на ней"

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Перевожу субтитры к немому кино. Правомочно ли поставить тире в следующей фразе:

> Мне всё равно, за кого она голосует — я собираюсь жениться на ней.

Или тут нужен другой знак препинания между предложениями?
Можно, конечно, и точку поставить, но тогда, на мой взгляд, теряется смысловое противопоставление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автору нужно решить, какую мысль он хочет передать:

1. Я собираюсь на ней жениться, так что мне все равно, за кого она голосует:

**Мне всё равно, за кого она голосует, — я собираюсь жениться на ней.**

Примечание. Каждый из знаков (вторая запятая и тире) ставится здесь на своем  основании.

2. Мне все равно за кого она голосует, потому что я собираюсь жениться на ней:

**Мне всё равно, за кого она голосует: я собираюсь жениться на ней.**

Примечание. Двоеточие "поглощает" вторую запятую.

См. [Знаки препинания между частями бессоюзного предложения](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185)

> Смысл таков: главгерою нет дела до избирательных предпочтений избранницы, он хочет жениться на ней несмотря ни на что.

Значит, основная часть высказывания заключена во второй части. [По Розенталю](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm) ставится тире:

> Примечание. Для разграничения случаев постановки двоеточия и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях можно исходить из следующего общего положения: если основная часть высказывания (соответствующая главному предложению в сложноподчиненных предложениях) заключена в первой части, а во второй (соответствующей придаточному предложению в сложноподчиненных предложениях) содержится пояснение, раскрытие содержания первой части, изложение какого-либо факта, указание на причину, то между частями ставится двоеточие; если же наоборот, основная часть высказывания заключена во второй части, а первая имеет подчиненное по смыслу значение (указывает время, условие и т.д.), то между частями ставится тире. Ср.: Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь (основное высказывание содержится в первой части, во второй указывается причина). – На улице проливной дождь – выйти невозможно (причина указывается в первой части, во второй следствие, вывод, что составляет основу высказывания). Ср. также при сохранении того же порядка частей бессоюзного сложного предложения: Молодежь ушла: на вечере стало скучно (ушла, потому что стало скучно). Молодежь ушла – на вечере стало скучно (ушла, поэтому стало скучно).

Comment: В оригинальном английском титре стоит тире, обозначающее интонационную паузу, поэтому первый вариант мне видится более оправданным. Смысл таков: главгерою нет дела до избирательных предпочтений избранницы, он хочет жениться на ней несмотря ни на что.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Мои сомнения были оттого, что я запутался, какая часть соответствует главному, а какая - придаточному предложению. Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Термин "придаточное предложение" нельзя употреблять, говоря о  бессоюзном сложном предложении (БСП). Розенталь говорит об "основной части высказывания".

Answer (score 2):

Если очень хочется смыслового противопоставления, ставьте зап-тире,

потому что запятая всё равно должна закрыть придаточное.

***Мне всё равно, за кого она голосует, — я собираюсь жениться на ней.***